# Links lose their css background-color hover attribute when changing background with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got a menu like this one :

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#" id="test">test</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="test2">test2</a></li>
</ul>
```

and css :

```
#menu li a:link {
background: transparent;
}

#menu li a:hover {
background-color: red;
}
```

At some point in my code I need to make the background of the links transparent again, so I make a :

```
$("#menu > li > a:link").css("background","transparent");
```

Which works but after that, my problem is that it seems to wipe the background-color attribute of the css hover. Indeed when I hover the links again nothing happens. If that helps when I add color:blue in the #menu li a:hover css, the text is blue when I hover but still no background-color.

I figured out a way to do the hover with jQuery but I would prefer to do it with css since in my opinion that's how it should be.
Is it a bug ? Is there any way to make the background transparent without wiping the hover css ?

Thanks in advance,

Nolhian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this same problem, and my solution was to make two separate classes rather than change the background color in jquery.

```
a.default:hover {  background-color: red; }
a.hovered:hover {  background-color: transparent; }  

$("#menu > li > a:link").removeClass("default");
$("#menu > li > a:link").addClass("hovered");
```

Comment: Thanks, I haven't thought of that ! I use it to uncolor the inactive menu links and color the right one. My problem is that :hover doesn't seem to do anything, when I do $("#"+menu_id+":link").addClass("colorme"); 
or
$("#"+menu_id).addClass("colorme");
with css:
a.colorme:link
{
background-color:yellow
}
a.colorme:hover
{
background:yellow;
color:red;
}
It works, my link background take the yellow color, but when I hover it takes the 
#menu li a:hover 
{ 
background-color:gray;
}
Instead of the colorme:hover.

Comment: OK got it, because #menu li a:hover overrode the overme:hover class I renamed it .uncolor:hover and added class="uncolor" to my links. Now it works fine ;)

Answer (score 1):

Target the background color directly, instead of simply "background":

```
#menu li a:link {
background-color: transparent;
}


$("#menu > li > a:link").css("background-color","transparent");
```

Comment: I really wished It worked but when I put background-color instead of background it doesn't, nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

No, the problem is with your CSS and the fact it's being overwritten.  Change:

```
 a:hover {background-color: yellow; }
```

to this:

```
 a:hover {background-color: yellow!important; }
```

Then it will work properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a "onmouseover" javascript hover.

Comment: Yes, but this would not work in browsers that do not support javascript (such as some mobile devices).

Comment: @TomasLycken: jQuery as a whole isn't going to work in browsers that don't support JavaScript.

Comment: @DavidThomas: I know. But doing the onmouseover effect in javascript instead of CSS would remove even more functionality (i.e. the hover effect) for those devices.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a side effect of how CSS works.  The :hover pseudo-class must be declared AFTER the :link pseudo-class.  Changing :link will reset :hover, so you need to reset your :hover as well.  One way to avoid this would be to move your CSS that alters the color from its initial setting into a class:

```
a:link {background-color: transparent; }
a:hover {background-color: yellow; }
a.myClass:link {background-color: cyan; }
```

And then

```
$("#menu > li > a:link").addClass("myClass");
```

And later

```
$("#menu > li > a:link").removeClass("myClass");
```